# Why can't RVM install Ruby 2.0.0?

Tags: ruby, rvm, failed-installation

I'm trying to install a fresh version of Ruby 2.0.0, via `rvm install 2.0.0`.

The installation fails with the following error:

```
Error running 'requirements_osx_port_install_port',
please read /Users/can/.rvm/log/ruby-1.9.3-p448/1373845387_port_install.log
```

Here is the log file:

```
% Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed

  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:01 --:--:--     0
100 16033    0 16033    0     0   6478      0 --:--:--  0:00:02 --:--:--  7091
100 51766    0 51766    0     0  18820      0 --:--:--  0:00:02 --:--:-- 20404
mkdir: /Users/can/.rvm/src/MacPorts-2.1.3: File exists
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed

  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:01 --:--:--     0
  0  825k    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:01 --:--:--     0
  7  825k    7 65536    0     0  25599      0  0:00:33  0:00:02  0:00:31 27899
 30  825k   30  256k    0     0  73029      0  0:00:11  0:00:03  0:00:08 77603
 56  825k   56  464k    0     0   101k      0  0:00:08  0:00:04  0:00:04  106k
 81  825k   81  672k    0     0   120k      0  0:00:06  0:00:05  0:00:01  162k
100  825k  100  825k    0     0   135k      0  0:00:06  0:00:06 --:--:--  185k
checking build system type... x86_64-apple-darwin12.4.0
checking host system type... x86_64-apple-darwin12.4.0
checking target system type... x86_64-apple-darwin12.4.0
checking MacPorts version... 2.1.3
checking for sw_vers... /usr/bin/sw_vers
checking for defaults... /usr/bin/defaults
checking for xcode-select... /usr/bin/xcode-select
checking Mac OS X version... 10.8.4
checking Xcode location... /Applications/Xcode5-DP.app/Contents/Developer
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether ln -s works... yes
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether we are using the GNU Objective C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for bsdmake... no
checking for pmake... no
checking for bzip2... /usr/bin/bzip2
checking for bzr... no
checking for chown... /usr/sbin/chown
checking for cp... /bin/cp
checking for cpio... /usr/bin/cpio
checking for cvs... /usr/bin/cvs
checking for diff... /usr/bin/diff
checking for dscl... /usr/bin/dscl
checking for dseditgroup... /usr/sbin/dseditgroup
checking for file... /usr/bin/file
checking for git... /usr/bin/git
checking for gnumake... /usr/bin/gnumake
checking for gnupatch... no
checking for gpatch... no
checking for gnutar... /usr/bin/gnutar
checking for gzip... /usr/bin/gzip
checking for hdiutil... /usr/bin/hdiutil
checking for hg... no
checking for launchctl... /bin/launchctl
checking for lipo... /usr/bin/lipo
checking for lsbom... /usr/bin/lsbom
checking for lzma... no
checking for make... /usr/bin/make
checking for mdfind... /usr/bin/mdfind
checking for mdls... /usr/bin/mdls
checking for mkbom... /usr/bin/mkbom
checking for mtree... /usr/sbin/mtree
checking for open... /usr/bin/open
checking for openssl... /usr/bin/openssl
checking for patch... /usr/bin/patch
checking for pax... /bin/pax
checking for rmdir... /bin/rmdir
checking for rsync... /usr/bin/rsync
checking for sed... /usr/bin/sed
checking for svn... /usr/bin/svn
checking for swig... no
checking for tar... /usr/bin/tar
checking for unzip... /usr/bin/unzip
checking for xar... /usr/bin/xar
checking for xcodebuild... /usr/bin/xcodebuild
checking for xcrun... /usr/bin/xcrun
checking for xz... no
checking for zip... /usr/bin/zip
checking for launchd... yes
checking for sed... (cached) /usr/bin/sed
checking which sed flag to use for extended regexp... -E (BSD)
checking for tar... (cached) /usr/bin/tar
checking whether tar supports -q... yes (bsdtar)
checking for tar... (cached) /usr/bin/tar
checking for gnutar... (cached) /usr/bin/gnutar
checking for which tar variant to use... /usr/bin/gnutar
checking for /usr/bin/gnutar --no-same-owner support... yes
checking for patch... (cached) /usr/bin/patch
checking for gpatch... no
checking for GNU (FSF) patch... /usr/bin/patch
checking how to mark unused variables... 
checking for gcc symbol visibility attribute... __attribute__((visibility("hidden")))
checking for the pthreads library -lpthreads... no
checking whether pthreads work without any flags... yes
checking for joinable pthread attribute... PTHREAD_CREATE_JOINABLE
checking if more special flags are required for pthreads... -D_THREAD_SAFE
checking how to run the Objective C preprocessor... gcc -E
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /usr/bin/grep
checking for egrep... /usr/bin/grep -E
checking for ANSI C header files... yes
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for sys/stat.h... yes
checking for stdlib.h... yes
checking for string.h... yes
checking for memory.h... yes
checking for strings.h... yes
checking for inttypes.h... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... yes
checking objc/objc.h usability... yes
checking objc/objc.h presence... yes
checking for objc/objc.h... yes
checking if linking libobjc requires pthreads... no
checking for Apple Objective-C runtime... yes
checking for GNU Objective C runtime... no
configure: Using Apple Objective-C runtime
checking for Apple Foundation library... yes
configure: WARNING: GNUSTEP_SYSTEM_ROOT is not defined in your environment, preventing the use of GNUstep's Foundation library
configure: Using Apple Foundation library
checking for CoreFoundation framework... yes
checking for SystemConfiguration framework... yes
checking for IOKit framework... yes
checking for CFNotificationCenterGetDarwinNotifyCenter... yes
checking for whether we will build daemondo... yes
checking for ports tree... configure: WARNING: No ports tree found
checking for MacPorts config directory... ${sysconfdir}/macports
checking for install user... root
checking for install group... admin
checking for macports user... macports
checking what permissions to use for installation directories... 0755
checking for Applications installation directory... /Applications/MacPorts
checking for Frameworks installation directory... /opt/local/Library/Frameworks
checking for Universal CPU architectures... x86_64 i386
checking how to run the C preprocessor... gcc -E
checking for ANSI C header files... (cached) yes
checking for dirent.h that defines DIR... yes
checking for library containing opendir... none required
checking for sys/wait.h that is POSIX.1 compatible... yes
checking limits.h usability... yes
checking limits.h presence... yes
checking for limits.h... yes
checking paths.h usability... yes
checking paths.h presence... yes
checking for paths.h... yes
checking sys/file.h usability... yes
checking sys/file.h presence... yes
checking for sys/file.h... yes
checking crt_externs.h usability... yes
checking crt_externs.h presence... yes
checking for crt_externs.h... yes
checking fcntl.h usability... yes
checking fcntl.h presence... yes
checking for fcntl.h... yes
checking sys/fcntl.h usability... yes
checking sys/fcntl.h presence... yes
checking for sys/fcntl.h... yes
checking sys/cdefs.h usability... yes
checking sys/cdefs.h presence... yes
checking for sys/cdefs.h... yes
checking err.h usability... yes
checking err.h presence... yes
checking for err.h... yes
checking sys/socket.h usability... yes
checking sys/socket.h presence... yes
checking for sys/socket.h... yes
checking sys/sysctl.h usability... yes
checking sys/sysctl.h presence... yes
checking for sys/sysctl.h... yes
checking readline/readline.h usability... yes
checking readline/readline.h presence... yes
checking for readline/readline.h... yes
checking readline/history.h usability... yes
checking readline/history.h presence... yes
checking for readline/history.h... yes
checking pwd.h usability... yes
checking pwd.h presence... yes
checking for pwd.h... yes
checking sys/paths.h usability... yes
checking sys/paths.h presence... yes
checking for sys/paths.h... yes
checking utime.h usability... yes
checking utime.h presence... yes
checking for utime.h... yes
checking for bzero... yes
checking for memset... yes
checking for fgetln... yes
checking for lockf... yes
checking for flock... yes
checking for setmode... yes
checking for strcasecmp... yes
checking for strncasecmp... yes
checking for strlcpy... yes
checking for copyfile... yes
checking for clearenv... no
checking for sysctlbyname... yes
checking if readlink conforms to POSIX 1003.1a... yes
checking CommonCrypto/CommonDigest.h usability... yes
checking CommonCrypto/CommonDigest.h presence... yes
checking for CommonCrypto/CommonDigest.h... yes
checking for Tcl configuration... found /usr/lib/tclConfig.sh
checking for existence of /usr/lib/tclConfig.sh... loading
checking for Tcl public headers... /usr/include
checking for tclsh... /usr/bin/tclsh
checking for Tcl package directory... /Library/Tcl
checking whether tclsh was compiled with threads... yes
checking for curl-config... /usr/bin/curl-config
checking sqlite3.h usability... yes
checking sqlite3.h presence... yes
checking for sqlite3.h... yes
checking sqlite3ext.h usability... yes
checking sqlite3ext.h presence... yes
checking for sqlite3ext.h... yes
checking for Tcl sqlite3 location... /usr/lib/sqlite3
checking for SQLite >= 3003011... yes
checking for Tcl Thread package... yes
checking how to build libraries... shared
checking that any existing MacPorts install can be upgraded... yes
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating src/programs/daemondo/Makefile
config.status: creating Doxyfile
config.status: creating Makefile
config.status: creating Mk/macports.autoconf.mk
config.status: creating doc/base.mtree
config.status: creating doc/prefix.mtree
config.status: creating doc/macosx.mtree
config.status: creating doc/macports.conf
config.status: creating doc/pubkeys.conf
config.status: creating portmgr/freebsd/Makefile
config.status: creating src/Makefile
config.status: creating src/machista1.0/Makefile
config.status: creating src/macports1.0/macports_autoconf.tcl
config.status: creating src/port1.0/port_autoconf.tcl
config.status: creating src/registry2.0/registry_autoconf.tcl
config.status: creating src/programs/Makefile
config.status: creating src/macports1.0/macports_fastload.tcl
config.status: creating setupenv.bash
config.status: creating src/pkg_mkindex.sh
config.status: creating src/config.h
config.status: src/config.h is unchanged
===> making all in doc
/bin/sh: make: No such file or directory
make: *** [all] Error 1
```

What should I do?

## Update:

I've uninstalled Xcode 5 Developer Preview 3 by simply throwing it into the trash and emptying it.

Now I get a different log:

```
% Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed

  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:05 --:--:--     0
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:06 --:--:--     0
100 32009    0 32009    0     0   4545      0 --:--:--  0:00:07 --:--:--  5162
100 51766    0 51766    0     0   7113      0 --:--:--  0:00:07 --:--:--  8044
mkdir: /Users/can/.rvm/src/MacPorts-2.1.3: File exists
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed

  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:01 --:--:--     0
  3  825k    3 32768    0     0  11994      0  0:01:10  0:00:02  0:01:08 13704
 21  825k   21  176k    0     0  48143      0  0:00:17  0:00:03  0:00:14 52975
 40  825k   40  336k    0     0  72379      0  0:00:11  0:00:04  0:00:07 77983
 61  825k   61  512k    0     0  91401      0  0:00:09  0:00:05  0:00:04 97180
 87  825k   87  720k    0     0   106k      0  0:00:07  0:00:06  0:00:01  146k
100  825k  100  825k    0     0   116k      0  0:00:07  0:00:07 --:--:--  182k
checking build system type... x86_64-apple-darwin12.4.0
checking host system type... x86_64-apple-darwin12.4.0
checking target system type... x86_64-apple-darwin12.4.0
checking MacPorts version... 2.1.3
checking for sw_vers... /usr/bin/sw_vers
checking for defaults... /usr/bin/defaults
checking for xcode-select... /usr/bin/xcode-select
checking Mac OS X version... 10.8.4
checking Xcode location... /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
checking Xcode version... 4.6.3
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... no
configure: error: in `/Users/can/.rvm/src/MacPorts-2.1.3':
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details
```

It's obvious that GCC could not be located.

When I type `gcc -v`, I get the following:

```
Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode5-DP.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
xcrun: Error: could not stat active Xcode path '/Applications/Xcode5-DP.app/Contents/Developer'. (No such file or directory)
```

Xcode 4 is installed properly with Command Line Tools. What should I do to make the system see Xcode 4's GCC?

Comment: Append the output of `rvm info` to your question. It sounds like RVM is confused or your path isn't right.

Comment: You have to update rvm, I got similar issue when trying to install ruby 2.0 with old rvm. So update rvm and then you will be able to install ruby 2.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be unrelated but it seems you are using Xcode 5 => `checking Xcode location... /Applications/Xcode5-DP.app/Contents/Developer` this is not yet released development/testing version which most likely should be used only with OSX 10.9 - which is also pre release.

Uninstall the new Xcode and command line tools and start fresh by downloading proper/release version of Xcode which is something around 4.6.3 - also you need to install again Command Line Tools from Xcode.

---

### Edit 1

Here is a link to description [how to switch default used Xcode](http://www.cocoanetics.com/2012/07/you-dont-need-the-xcode-command-line-tools/) ([provided by Can Sürmeli](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17644942/why-cant-rvm-install-ruby-2-0-0/17651005?noredirect=1#comment25786806_17651005))

Comment: I think you might be right. Could you please check my update to the original question.

Comment: still it uses the newer command line tools, check for command line tools application and remove all copies of it - then install CLT which is available for your system (not any beta).

Comment: With the help of knowledge on this page (http://www.cocoanetics.com/2012/07/you-dont-need-the-xcode-command-line-tools/), I easily managed to change which version of Xcode's CLT, Terminal was seeing. Afterwards, the RVM procedure was done without a problem.

Comment: also, thanks a lot for pointing me in the right direction. much appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

If you're on OSX, you need to install XCode, if you think it's installed, then it might be corrupt, so re-install.

If you don't have it, you can just install the Command Line Tools for XCode from

https://developer.apple.com/downloads

The latest version is "Command Line Tools (OS X Mountain Lion) for Xcode - April 2013"

Comment: Per the configure output XCode is installed: `checking for xcode-select... /usr/bin/xcode-select`, as is gcc and the compiler works.

Comment: @the Tin Man, since XCode 4.3, Command Line Tools are not installed by default

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is question is a little bit obvious but is important to good answer.

> /bin/sh: make: No such file or directory

The error message said that didn't find make command. Is it install your computer?

Comment: Configure said it found make: `checking for make... /usr/bin/make`. Then `/bin/sh` said it couldn't. It sounds like a PATH issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing make and some dependencies.

1. Run `rvm implode`. This will let you start over by completely removing whatever you've got from RVM. Make sure you removed .rvm directories like `/Users/can/.rvm/`
2. Install `make`.
3. Install `bash curl git patch`.
4. Then install the Ruby dependencies:

   ```
   osx-gcc-installer libksba openssl libreadline git zlib1g libyaml libsqlite3 sqlite3 libxml2 libxslt autoconf libc6 libgdbm ncurses automake libtool bison pkg-config
   ```
5. Install `openjdk ant`.
6. Finally, install RVM with Ruby:

   ```
   \curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --ruby
   ```

Comment: This might be the right answer, though configure was able to find XCode and make. It sounds like RVM is confused and is not passing the right parameters or setting the path correctly.

Comment: the log is from configure - it fails itself